# How can I insert dynamic number of rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor, temp-tables

I have a material table as source table as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MATERIAL (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CATEGORY_ID int NOT NULL,
    SECTION_ID int NOT NULL,
    STATUS_ID int NOT NULL
)
```

also I have a Order table as the target table as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ORDER (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    MATERIAL_ID int NOT NULL
)
```

I am sending ome data to SQL server to a Stored Procedure and have the following Temp Table created

```
DECLARE @temptable TABLE (
    CATEGORY_ID int NOT NULL,
    SECTION_ID int NOT NULL,
    STATUS_ID int NOT NULL,
    COUNT int NOT NULL
)
```

and had it filled with data as follows :

```
CATEGORY_ID    SECTION_ID    STATUS_ID    COUNT
-----------    ----------    ---------    -----
     3             8             1          10
     8             2             2          11 
     4             6             1           8
```

What I want is to match COUNT number of materials from MATERIAL table which matches ith the given CATEGORY_ID, SECTION_ID and STATUS_ID triple of the same row; then insert those records's IDs to the target table, ORDER.

How can I acomplish this task?

Regards.

Comment: This  sounds like a badly explained depleting inventory question. `MATERIAL` is a table of inventory. You then assemble a Bill of Materials (BoM) in `@temptable` describing the items and quantities which are needed to fulfill an order. The question is some odd variation on how to use the BoM to pull inventory out of `MATERIAL`, though without keeping track of any previously consumed inventory, and insert the results into `ORDER`. Is that even close?

Comment: Due to heavy item count, decreasing roundtrips and performance is vital for the project. In order to prevent multiple trips to DB we serialize the object with children into XML and then process all data at the Databse server. With this technique we can insert thousands of materials with one trip and observe a performance similiar to several items.

Comment: @user3021830 updated answer to give you a method to doing it without cursors which I believe will hinder performance. The last response is likely the cleanest for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Threw away a bunch of previous work now that I think I understand requirement.

Here's a working  [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/430c1/1/0):

This generates a data set called GENROWS that contains rows equal to the count of the max count in temptable. It does this by using a recursive Common table expression (CTE) to generate 1 row for each count of the max count in temptable.
It then uses this data set to join to temptable and material to generate the # of times the material needs to be inserted in order.

I'm not a big fan of using reserved words so I adjusted `order` to `morder` and I would recommend adjusting column `count` otherwise you'll be stuck wrapping words in []'s from time to time.

NOTE: This assumes there will not be duplicates (records with same category_ID, Section_Id and Status_ID) in material table.  If there are; then this may or may not behave as expected.

And lastly now that I have a better understanding of what you're after I'm not positive you'll see much of a performance gain compared to using cursors.  As the rows have to be generated somehow.  This still may work a bit faster because we generate the set and insert all at once as opposed to individually.  But there's overhead with producing storing and retrieving the data set produced which may offset this gain.  Only testing would tell.

```
WITH 
GenRows (RowNumber, Val) AS (
   -- Anchor member definition
   SELECT 1 AS RowNumber, (Select max(count) val from temptable) val
   UNION ALL
   -- Recursive member definition
   SELECT a.RowNumber + 1  AS RowNumber, a.val
   FROM   GenRows a
   WHERE  a.RowNumber < a.val
)
Insert into morder (Material_ID)  
SELECT A.ID
FROM material A
INNER JOIN temptable B
   on A.Category_ID = B.Category_ID
  and A.Section_Id = B.Section_Id
  and A.Status_Id = B.Status_ID
INNER JOIN GenRows
  on GenRows.RowNumber <= b.[count]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the update. But it still does not seem to achieve what I require. I have just made tiny changes on the query and updated the required number of materials in @temptable, Unfortunately the ode does not run correct results now. Please see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ebb92/1

Comment: I am failing to understand the requirement. It was my impression you only wanted to insert records into order that matched precisely the count of data records in material  So in the fiddle example... temptable has 3,8,1,3. where 3 is the last 3 is count.  If you look at the material table there are records that are 3,8,1 but the count of those is > 3 thus no data matched. same for all the other records in temptable.  Now if you're after inserting any random set of records from temptable with the count of what's in temptable (meaning pick any 3 of the 10 matching the 3,8,1) that can be done too

Comment: I am sorry if I did not provide the details right. Let's example the project in sets theory. Material table is the universal set. All items reside there and  no items which do not belong to this table may be added to order table. The users sends dta which I fill into @temptable, which describes the spesifications of the material to be picked and the count as number of materials to be picked. What I need is to find materials matching the spesc, pick "count" number of them and then save these material's ids into the order table.

Comment: @user3021830 Now that I think I understand what you're after (I was thinking generate test data when this seems more about actual operational data)  I've updated the fiddle and results; and cleaned out the garbage from earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the solution. I should have used CURSOR. The following code does the trick :

```
DECLARE @MATERIAL_ID int
DECLARE @CATEGORY_ID int
DECLARE @SECTION_ID int
DECLARE @STATUS_ID int
DECLARE @COUNT int

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FOR
SELECT
    CATEGORY_ID,
    SECTION_ID,
    STATUS_ID,
    COUNT
FROM
    @temptable 

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @CATEGORY_ID, @SECTION_ID, @STATUS_ID, @COUNT
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO
            dbo.ORDER
            (MATERIAL_ID)
        SELECT
            TOP (@COUNT) ID
        FROM
            dbo.MATERIAL AS m
        WHERE
            m.CATEGORY_ID = @CATEGORY_ID
            AND m.SECTION_ID = @SECTION_ID
            AND m.STATUS_ID = @STATUS_ID

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @CATEGORY_ID, @SECTION_ID, @STATUS_ID, @COUNT
    END
CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Comment: You're losing some of the performance you gained by using cursors.  in a RDBMS when you can process using set logic you'll achieve better performance.